# Differences in git diff

Tags: git, diff

The values `c6e77d0` and `10c29ac` are two different commits on two different branches.

```
$ git ls-tree c6e77d0 NAExtractWeb/pom.xml
100644 blob 010f766a07c83bbf0f163155e9dd15ceb41e65d8    NAExtractWeb/pom.xml

$ git ls-tree 10c29ac NAExtractWeb/pom.xml
100644 blob f1e0f632487e928ecf7c6ea796b894a652853087    NAExtractWeb/pom.xml

$ git diff c6e77d0..10c29ac -- pom.xml

$ git diff 010f766a0..f1e0f6324
diff --git a/010f766a0 b/f1e0f6324
index 010f766..f1e0f63 100644
--- a/010f766a0
+++ b/f1e0f6324
```

The differences between the two commits on `pom.xml` are none. But if we get the files values(treeish) from `ls-tree` and compare those, there are some differences. What am I missing ?

Comment: Please add a comment before asking to close.

Comment: It's not at all clear what is going on here. It might be instructive to extract the two blobs directly (`git cat-file -p <hash>` on each) and compare those. Note that if you are using Git-LFS and `pom.xml` is enormous, you might have two different placeholder files whose final content matches and the filtering is what's producing this effect, but that seems a bit unlikely to me.

Comment: I hate to say this but the same command is showing different results. May be this might be a bug.